# How to set default values for argparse metavar arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am using argparse so my python script can take in arguments. With argparse, I'm using metavar so I can take in 2 arguments for a single flag. I want to be able to set default values for these arguments if they are not specified. How can I set default values to my metavar arguments?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Sample ArgumentParser')    
parser.add_argument("--stuff", nargs=2, metavar=('arg1', 'arg2'))
```

Comment: Metavar just controls the names used in the `usage` and `help`.  There's a separate `default` parameter.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean? @Ben answer below doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @hpaulj says, just use the `default` parameter:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Sample ArgumentParser')
parser.add_argument(
    "--stuff",
    nargs=2,
    metavar=('arg1', 'arg2'),
    default=('arg1def', 'arg2def')
)

args = parser.parse_args()
print('Args:', args)
```

Output:

```
λ python tmp.py
Args: Namespace(stuff=('arg1def', 'arg2def'))

λ python tmp.py --stuff bob ross
Args: Namespace(stuff=['bob', 'ross'])
```

Comment: I tried that but when I use default and pass in a tuple I get `error: argument --stuff: expected 2 arguments`

Comment: If you provide the '--stuff' flag, you also have to provide 2 values.  The defaults are used when you don't use '--stuff' at all.